# how to use select in count in where

Tags: sql

what is right syntax for this statment:

```
select *
from notices
where count(select * from notices where no_type = 'p'
        or no_type = 'n') > 3
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? that query makes little sense

Comment: syntax for what??

Comment: Perhaps you meant to do `select count(*) from notices where no_type = 'p' or no_type = 'n'` in the subquery.

Comment: please add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way to write a query but if you really need to have it, this may work

```
select * from notices as a
where (select count(*) from notices as b where no_type = 'p'
    a.someColumn = b.someColumn) > 3 or (select count(*) from notices as c where
    or no_type = 'n' and a.someColumn = c.someColumn) > 3
```